# How to select the previous row in a group with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, pandas-groupby

I need to select the row previous to when `discharge_location` is `Readmit` within a group. Then set the ID and Discharge_location to a dictionary.

sample df

```
ID     admit     discharge    discharge_location   first
20     3-4-2018  3-6-2018     Home                 1
20     2-2-2018  2-6-2018     Home                 0
20     2-5-2018  2-23-2018    Readmit              0
30     1-2-2018  2-3-2018     Rehab                1
30     1-15-2018 1-18-2018    Readmit              0
30     1-20-2018 1-24-2018    Home                 0
40     1-20-2018 1-24-2018    Home                 0
40     1-20-2018 1-24-2018    Home                 0
40     1-20-2018 1-24-2018    Home                 0
```

final result

```
ID    Discharge_location
20    Home
30    Rehab
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.loc[df[df.discharge_location=='Readmit'].index-1]
Out[1519]: 
   ID     admit discharge discharge_location  first
1  20  2-2-2018  2-6-2018               Home      0
3  30  1-2-2018  2-3-2018              Rehab      1
```

From MartyB

```
df.loc[df[df.discharge_location=='Readmit'].index-1][['ID','discharge_location']].set_index('ID').to_dict()
```

Comment: you understand this correctly. Is it possible to just select the ID and discharge location?

Comment: Here is the final version per Wen's help. `df.loc[df[df.discharge_location=='Readmit'].index-1][['ID','discharge_location']].set_index('ID').to_dict()`

Comment: @MartyB yep , also update your own approach , thank you :-)